# Kill Snowflake queries from Spark Connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to kill Snowflake queries using the  Spark connector ? Alternatively is there a way to grab the last last query id or session id in Spark to kill it outside of Spark.

The use case is user controlled long running Spark jobs with long running Snowflake queries. When a user is killing the Spark jobs , the current Snowflake query keeps on running (for many hours )

Thank you

Comment: If this happens frequently, you may want to set a Snowflake query timeout for your Spark connections.  This can be done with an ALTER SESSION statement when you first connect to Snowflake.  You can also grab the current session at that time for later use.

Comment: How do I grab the session ? The Spark connector uses a different session for each query

Comment: @Stéphane You could set this value at user level that is used for connection: `ALTER USER <name> SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 300;`

Comment: Would that not kill all the queries that exceed 300s event if the user does not kill the job ?

Comment: You can also pass the statement_timeout_in_seconds as part of the session:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#additional-options.  And I would think you could use a preaction or postaction script to grab the session_id, as well.

Comment: Yes - that option has nothing to do with killing a query.  But you could set it to limit the run-time of a query regardless.  As for canceling the query, it might be helpful to set a query_tag in your code with something unique that makes it easy to look up your query_id and cancel the query manually in Snowflake.  This would also be set with the session options.

Comment: Yes , I think I can make it work with a query tag - thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You can also use the function [*LAST_QUERY_ID*](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html) for last executed query in general.

Answer (score 0):

Log into snowflake UI (or use snowsql) with the same user you use for spark, and run following:

```
use database <your_db>;
use warehouse <your wh>;

select  
    query_id, query_text, execution_status, error_message, start_time, end_time     
from 
    table(information_schema.query_history( RESULT_LIMIT => 10) );
```

This should show you your recent queries. Find the one that is in RUNNING state, copy its QUERY_ID, and use to run this:

```
select system$cancel_query('<your query id here>');
```